# Coin Flip Grouping Results (C#)

Tags: c#, grouping, coin-flipping

I was having trouble with an assignment I have, where after displaying results of a coin flip program, where it would typically look like: (This is for C# by the way)

Heads

Tails

Tails

Tails

etc.

I now have to group them in rows. For example, if the name were Group(10, 4),
10 would mean the total flips of the "coin" and 4 would be how the results would be grouped:

Heads Tails Tails Tails

Tails Heads Tails Tails

Heads Heads

I'm confused as to whether everything in the Flips() should be in the Groups() along with a for loop that would manipulate the sorting of the results? Or totally separate? I'm also stumped on how to begin..

Sorry, but help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;

namespace heads_tails
{
class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int v = 0; v <= 10; v++)
        Flip ();

    }
    static void Flip()
    {
        int lo, hi, n;
        Random r = new Random ();
        lo = 0;
        hi = 2;
        n = r.Next(lo, hi);
        if (n == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Heads");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("Tails");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint (since this is an assignment):

One way to do it is to pass parameters into `Flip()`.

Make it instead

`Flip(int flipNumber, int groupBy)`

This way you can determine within `Flip()` whether you have to start a new line when you print.  (Your value for `groupBy` would be 4 in your example.)

Comment: i figured out how to have them written next to each other, but I'm still having trouble writing a code for "groupBy".